# I want to make a custom dojo JsonRest store, there is a part that I don't understand

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to make a custom dojo JsonRest Store, there is a part that I don't understand in the `query` function.

This is the part that I don't fully understand:

```
var results = xhr("GET", {
        url: this.target + (query || ""),
        handleAs: "json",
        headers: headers
});
results.total = results.then(function(){
        var range = results.ioArgs.xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Range");
        return range && (range = range.match(/\/(.*)/)) && +range[1];
});
return QueryResults(results);
```

As far as I understand, it tries to get an array of object from the url and then append the total of records to the `results` which is a `deferred`? Can you do that? And it seems like the function returns a boolean instead of an integer.

Anyway I tried to replicate that part of code in my own way.

```
var result = request.post(this.target + "/get", 
{
    data: dojo.toJson(requestParam),
    handleAs: "json",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
});

var results = result.then
(
    function (result)
    {
        return (result.entities?result.entities:{});
    }
);

results.total = result.then
(
    function (result)
    {
        return result.total;
    }
);

results.total.then(function(total){
    console.log("total results: ", total);
});

return QueryResults(results);
```

But the `total` is undefined, I think it's because the `results` is a deferred not an array. I just don't get it. How do I recreate this function in my own way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to answer your questions about how the `query` method returns, yes, the `total` is a property on the returned value.  Both the return value and `total` are allowed to be immediate values or promises.

In the first code you pasted, `results.total` will ordinarily return a number, not a boolean.          `return range && (range = range.match(/\/(.*)/)) && +range[1];` will first attempt to pull the contents of the Content-Range header following a forward slash, and if successful, will coerce that to a number and return it.

RE your code, you are likely finding `total` is undefined because `dojo/request` returns promises (preferable over returning full Deferreds), and promises are frozen in browsers that support ES5, which will prevent you from adding the `total` property to it.  You will likely want to use `lang.delegate` to create a new object based on the promise to get around this limitation.

Also, your default value for the results should be an empty array, not an empty object.

Comment: When I use delegate will it return a promise or a deferred?